# Is it possible to integrate a gradle Library project to an android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

First of all I'm new to Gradle and I've a limited knowledge in it.

I've an android project. What I need is to integrate a Gradle library project with my project.

So my question is, IS it possible to add Gradle library project with an android Project without converting the android project to Gradle Project???

Can any one Help me to find the solution? I'm using eclipse as the tool.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what is the build system of your android project ?

Comment: You can convert the gradle project back to the old build system. But you should use gradle, so the better course of action would be to convert your current project to gradle.

Comment: You are correct but unfortunately It takes time to convert my project to gradle as it contains many Library files. And its an urgent requirement In future I definitely will, in fact I have to.. Any ways Thanks for feedback Xaver and Snicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you can do it

Try these methods

**Method1**: Manually reconfigure your gradle based library project folder structure like your regular eclipse projects

**Method2**: Import project then Properties > java build path > source tab....remove path to src....add path to java folder in the source code using add folder button... then build your project as usual

[image]